# jQuery slider. Cannot pass a simple variable into the .slider function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have the following

```
min = 1000;
jQuery('#slider').slider({
     range: "max",
     value: 9000,  
     min: 1000,    
     max: 1000000, 
     step: 500,    
});
```

All I want to do is simply pass the variable "min" into it. Whatever I have tried hasn't worked:

```
min = 1000;
jQuery('#slider').slider({
     range: "max",
     value: 9000,  
     min: min,    
     max: 1000000, 
     step: 500,    
 });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/b58Yd/

I have added `var` before your variable declaration and removed the final comma from the list of arguments ....

```
var min = 1000;
$('#slider').slider({range: "max",
     value: 9000,  
     min: min,    
     max: 1000000,
     step: 500

});
```